# How to execute REST API with elevated privileges in SharePoint Online?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Is there any way, by which I can fetch all the list items from a SharePoint List (Whether user has permission or not any list items)?

In other terms, I need to execute REST API with elevated privileges or any another way by which I can get all the Items. I am using SharePoint Online so I don't want to go for any server side coding but just want to use REST API or JSOM.

Comment: I do not think what you are trying to achieve is possible using Json/REST. Refer this link for more information. -- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126045/what-is-the-permission-level-for-rest-query

Comment: Thank you Rohit for your response. This is really helpful for me.